# Is it possible to get Public Data from Facebook Users via Graph API without having users permission?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

There are a lot of question about similar topic, but none of them is actual and gives an answer.

I try to get public data from random facebook user via the facebook graph api.

First of all [here is the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user) about getting user informations, and the endpoint looks like this:

> GET /v2.9/{user-id} HTTP/1.1

Now I try this in the [facebook graph explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/).  But now I need the {user-id}

**-Where or how do I get this user-id when I have the url to the users profile?**

Lets say the user-id is given - to get the user-id I used [findmyfbid.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20201201114535/https://findmyfbid.com/)

But the only response I get is the public name of the user and not more.

**-So is it possible to get public user profile data, withouth having the users permission for your app? And if not, where is this written in the documentation?**

Comment: _“But the only response I get is the public name of the user and not more”_ – did you _ask_ for any other fields (as you have to since API v2.4) …?

Comment: But in general, you _should not_ do this. Data of users that have not connected to your app simply is none of your business. Have them log in to your app, then you get their app-scoped user id, and don’t have to use questionable 3rd-party services.

Comment: Yes I asked for more fields, in the explorer you can choose more - just try it by yourself. - "you should not do this" - this is very true. It is for a research project at the universtiy. So I think it is not possible to do this. Where can I find this information in the graph documentation? would be nice.

Comment: there is no allowed way to do this. you MUST authorize users to get any data. after that, you can just use the /me endpoint with fields: /me?fields?name,email,...

Comment: You should be able to get a few more fields (such as first_name, last_name, link) - but pretty much anything that goes beyond that needs at leas `public_profile` permission from the user.

Comment: How about getting the public data from the loggedin users Friends? Is that possible?